# Laravel routing to a js script on my server and load that to page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I would like to route a request that looks like this:
https://sub.domain.nl/tracking/MM-123/tracker.js

To my javascript in this directory:
Resources/js/Scrips/tracking/tracker.js

However, it looks like the server/laravel is looking for this script:
https://sub.domain.nl/tracking/MM-123/tracker.js

In the /public folder.

However, I want it load it just like a normal view / page from the server.

My web.php router:

```
Route::group([], function () {
  Route::get('/tracking/{script}/tracker.js', [TrackingScriptController::class, 'index'])->name('tracking');
});
```

My TrackingScriptController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class TrackingScriptController extends Controller
{
    public function index($script)
    {
        // Construct the path to the script file
        $filePath = resource_path("js/Scripts/Tracking/tracker.js");

        // Check if the file exists
        if (!File::exists($filePath)) {
            // You can return a 404 or some other error if the file is not found
            abort(404, 'Script not found');
        }

        // Read the contents of the file
        $scriptContents = File::get($filePath);

        // Return the contents with the correct Content-Type header
        return Response::make($scriptContents, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/javascript']);
    }
}
```

?>

But the browser keeps giving 404 page not found, in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () tracker.js
```

So it looks like my laravel app is trying to look for this .js file inside of the public app. When I remove .js from the URL like this:
https://sub.domain.nl/tracking/MM-123/tracker

And my web.php to this:

```
Route::group([], function () {
  Route::get('/tracking/{script}/tracker.', [TrackingScriptController::class, 'index'])->name('tracking');
});
```

It works fine.

I'm using Laravel (Breeze starter kit) + Inertia + Vue.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I have no idea unfortunately after trying a lot of different things.

Comment: Nothing to do with Laravel, this is a server task, depends on if you are using Apache or nginx or even PHP built-in server -which is not recommended for production-.

Comment: @hassan I added rewrite rules to my .htaccess in the public folder:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tracking/([^/]+)/tracker\.js$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

It still looks like it's searching for a physical file on the public folder, still get the 404.

Comment: btw, why you do not simply put the tracker.js in the public dir? or at least to symlink it?

Comment: @hassan because I want to dynamically load data from my databases into it, like tenant id etc.

Comment: This seems like a very convoluted way to achieve something that's already a solved problem in Vanilla JS, not to mention countless libraries and frameworks. if you want to load data from databases into JS you're much better off using an API of sorts. This can  then request data from you backend.